# Making SwiftUI views with clear backgrounds?

Tags: swiftui, xcode12, xcode12.5

I've tried any number of methods to get the white background here to be clear. Nothing seems to work.

[image: List over bluebackground]

```swift
struct OverlayChatView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                ChatMessageCell()
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .background(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}

struct ChatMessageCell: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fill)
            Text("This is a chat message of certain length to try to force a wrap in the preview.")
        }
    }
}

struct OverlayChatView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            OverlayChatView()
                .frame(maxWidth: 300.0, maxHeight: 300.0)
                .background(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of people seem to be having the problem and some solve it with the non-starter:

```swift
.onAppear {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

I can set the individual list item cells to a specific opaque background color. I can't even set the `OverlayChatView` or `List` to a solid color, let alone clear.

iOS 14 (simulator, not device)

Comment: After inspecting the view hierarchy in Xcode, SwiftUI is still creating UITableViews, and it seems the only solution is to set the appearance of all table views. This means all our other (non-SwiftUI) code has to explicitly set its background colors.

Comment: This is now broken on iOS 16 :(

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped with `ForEach` and set the background color.

```
struct OverlayChatView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 5) {  item in //<-- Here
                    ChatMessageCell()
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.blue) //<-- Here
            }
            .background(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use `colorMultiply` as well.

```
struct OverlayChatView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                    ChatMessageCell()
                
            }.colorMultiply(Color.blue) //<-- Here
            .background(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to make the background of the list blue, I'm trying to make it clear (so that _whatever_ is behind it comes through).

Comment: But you can do one thing declare one color var inside the view and use it where ever you require.

Comment: No, I can't. Imagine if the background were an image.