# SwiftUI List Background Colour

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI, I have a List that on occasion dosnt have enough items to fill it all, as a result im seeing the white 'background' at the bottom.

[image]

```
List {
    ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
    ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
    ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
}
.cornerRadius(15)
.border(Color.black, width: 2)
```

Ive tired applying the background item, but made no difference i.e.

```
List {
    ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
    ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
    ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
}
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(15)
.border(Color.black, width: 2)
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Does this your answer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67514340/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan unfortunately not, setting the background has no effect on area where isn't isn't enough cells

Comment: Wrapped your list with zstack

Answer (score 0):

Please try using:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
       ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
       ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
       ListItemCell(item: "xxx")
    }
}
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(15)
.border(Color.black, width: 2)
```